# Where is Jennifer's husband?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

Jennifer is 21 years older than her son Douglas. 
6 years from now, Jennifer will be 5 times as old as Douglas.

Question: Where is Jennifer's husband most likely to be right now?

Comment: This really is more of a joke than a puzzle.

Comment: @xnor Well, it *does* have a clear solution as to the ages of Jennifer and Douglas. And in the original version, there was a "where is he most likely to be?" disclaimer, which cuts out a lot of the nitpicks from the two joke answers below.

Comment: Jennifer's husband is [fishing in Canada.](https://ia701200.us.archive.org/13/items/WhatIsTheNameOfThisBook/What-is-the-Name-of-this-Book.pdf#page=211) (with apologies to Raymond Smullyan)

Comment: @David - Which is a subset of my "... could be anywhere in the world" :P

Comment: Perhaps the puzzle could be improved by changing the final question to "Where is Douglas's father?"

Comment: The original question was not phrased well.  I had edited it to resolve that, not realizing the importance of the "most likely" part.  I've edited again, restoring that key aspect of the question.  :)

Comment: this is the most amazing puzzle I have encountered nowadays!

Comment: It just _seems_ like this question has already been asked [here](https://www.logisch-gedacht.de/forum/?board=12&thema=43) quite a while before...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Let's define $J$=Jennifer and $D$=Douglas.
The problem can be rewritten as:

$J=D+21$
$J+6=5(D+6)$

According to my math, Douglas is $D=(-\frac{3}{4})$ years old, which means $-9$ months. Pregnancy lasts for nine months, so **Jennifer's husband is in the bed with her right now**.

Comment: That's actually the milk man..

Comment: Actually, you can't know yet whether Douglas is a male or a female...

Comment: maybe replace the name douglas with Pat, and the word son, with child

Comment: actually they may not be in bed. But he's most probably inside her

Comment: @leoll2 - "_Actually, you can't know yet whether Douglas is a male or a female_". Yes, and I can imagine some feminist visiting this post and calling all of us "male chauvinist pigs". :P

Comment: @UserAnonymous We must be doing something right then.

Comment: To be nitpicky, human gestation *averages* 280 days.  The number of days in 9 months is between 273 and 276, depending on which month you start counting from, so we can really only say Jennifer's husband will be in bed with her - on average - within the next 7 days.  And even if you massaged the numbers to pinpoint the day, you can't be sure they are in bed *right now*, you could be a few hours off due to rounding errors.

Answer (score 27):

Jennifer's husband is busy in business meetings, while Douglas's dad is with Jennifer.

Comment: I was wondering when someone was going to give this kind of amswer, ahahah

Answer (score 20):

As mentioned in [leoll2's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/10543/10342) above, the Maths part of the question is the simultaneous solution of the two equations which relate the respective ages of Jennifer and Douglas:

$$J=D+21$$
$$J+6=5(D+6)$$

These provide the answer $D = -3/4$ years, or roughly $-9$ months, which could lead one to conclude what leoll2 concluded.

However,

1) It is not necessary that Jennifer's husband must have necessarily fathered Douglas. (No offence meant, I only mean it is not specified in the puzzle.)

2) Biologically, pregnancy doesn't *always* have to last 9 months. So, one can not deny the possibility of Douglas being born after 8 and a half months instead of nine.

So, Jennifer's husband could be anywhere in this world, or could even be dead. Particularly, if he hasn't fathered Douglas, and pregnancy did last exactly 9 months, then he must **not** be around at the time of conceiving (stark opposite conclusion from the same data).

This is not a well designed puzzle. Sorry for being a killjoy :(

Comment: well you're no fun

Comment: @basher - I know, but I think I'm not oversimplifying :)

Comment: Plus, the best part of having rep 1 is an immunity to possible down-votes :P

Comment: -1 The trick of solving a puzzle is understanding the puzzle, this puzzle clearly required thinking in generalized terms and this answer clearly fails at that. And if you actually feel sorry for being a 'killjoy', there is a simple solution: just don't post answers like this ;-)

Comment: Yes, and as mentioned in my other comment, human gestation actually averages 280 days, which is up to a week beyond nine months, depending on which months are included.

Comment: I'm wondering who you felt would be offended lol these are not real people

Comment: _"Particularly, if he hasn't fathered Douglas, and pregnancy did last exactly 9 months, then he must not be around at the time of conceiving (stark opposite conclusion from the same data)"_ This is incorrect.

Comment: @Michael - And I thought I was the only dork around here :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Why is it wrong? If he was around at that time (as in, he caught them in the act), either Jennifer, or Douglas' father, or both, could be dead :P

Comment: @UserAnonymous: Who's to say he wasn't there? Watching, participating... You've simply assumed that the husband would not approve but there is no _evidence_ to support your assumption.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Haha. Yes, right! How careless of me :P